# Make select option 'selected' based on database query result

Tags: jquery, select, selected

Have a script which queries a database and highlights the returned result in the select field.

I am using codeigniter with jquery, jquery mobile and jquery ui.

my view syntax is:

```
<select id="defaulttreated" name="defaulttreated" data-mini="true" data-theme="a">
    <option value="0" selected></option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

my view jquery is:

```
function gettreating() {
    //populate treating  start
    var deliveryaddress = $("#deliveryaddress").val();
    //populate treating end
    $.post('gettreatingdefault', {
        deliveryid: deliveryaddress
    }, function (result) {
        alert(result);
        var el = $('#defaulttreated');
        el.val(result).attr('selected', true).siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');
        el.selectmenu("defaulttreated", true);
    });
}
```

I have verified that the value of result is working. currently the alert returns 'yes'.

How do I make `yes` selected in the `defaulttreated` select box?

Currently the error message is:

`Error: no such method 'defaulttreated' for selectmenu widget instance` and points to line 3 of jquery.min.js

Comment: May I ask what this line is for `el.selectmenu("defaulttreated", true);` it's the one giving you the error, not to say the `selected` part is right because your not getting the option element but are trying to set the property to the select

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
function gettreating(){
  $.post('gettreatingdefault.php',
    {deliveryid: $("#deliveryaddress").val()},
    function(result){
      $('#defaulttreated option').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
        if($(this).val() === result){
          $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = $('#defaulttreated');
var result = "yes";// just to fix the value
el.val(result);
alert(el.val() + el.find('option:selected').text());//show the selected option and its text
```

NOTE: You do not have to "unselect" the other options unless this select has multiple on.
working example: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/57KsV/)